# Hi I'm having trouble customizing authentication in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am a newbie and I am designing Django authentication software
My problem is that I have to check four separate levels for which there are predefined codes in the permission check.
A model class named province and a model class named city and a model named Student
My review model is such that I should be able to give a user the membership of the central office or the membership of a province or the membership of a city in a province.
The user can only be for one of these situations

My models is like this

```
class Province(models.Model):
    province_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
    province_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('Province'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['province_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.province_title

class Center(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    center_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('Name of the training center'), null=True)
    center_title_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=_('Code of the training center'), null=True)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Province'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("center")
        verbose_name_plural = _("centers")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.center_title`

class CulturalUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class UserPositions(models.Model):
    class Position(models.TextChoices):
        UNIVERSITY_STUDENT = '1', _('University student')
        TRAINING_CENTER = '2', _('Training center')
        PROVINCE = '3', _('Province')
        CENTRAL_OFFICE = '4', _('Central office')

    user = models.ForeignKey(CulturalUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))
    position = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('Access level'), choices=Position.choices,
                                default=Position.UNIVERSITY_STUDENT)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    center = models.ForeignKey(Center, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position
```

please direct me

According to the search I did, I could not find the right sources in my question mode

Answer (score 0):

You can either [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [substitute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) an user model. Quotting the documentation:

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

[A full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

Django's user models counts with [permissions and authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) and [groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#groups) out of the box. So, instead of choices fields you would have four groups, for which you would handle access with permissions.

- University student
- Training center
- Province
- Central office

Here is one version of your model:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, 
        verbose_name=_('Province')
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Center(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, 
        verbose_name=_('Name of the training center'), 
        null=True,
    )
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, 
        verbose_name=_('Code of the training center'),
        null=True,
    )
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        verbose_name=_('Province')
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("center")
        verbose_name_plural = _("centers")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(AbstractUser):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

    center = models.ForeignKey(
        Center, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        blank=True, null=True,
    )
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Note that I used AbstractUser, like you did, but you can do an even deeper customization with AbstractBaseUser, as shown in the example I linked above.

Comment: Yes
Your model is correct
But if, for example, I have a user who needs to log in to the system as a provincial user and a student, considering that it is only possible to assign one role to each user, I will face a problem.
If it is possible, please provide a solution so that I can manage the accesses through a multiple-by-multiple field and a separate table.
For example, use the class UserPositions

Comment: Users can have multiple groups. Its a many-to-many relationship in the underlying authentication system. So as the permissions.

Comment: Let me explain again
If necessary, one of the users can enter the system both as a student studying and as a provincial user
Considering that each user has only one record, it is necessary to define a new user for the desired person.
I want to show all the person's accesses without adding a new user by showing a modal window after authentication and allow the user to enter the same level of access by clicking on any of the accesses.

Comment: One user can have two groups, he can login both as student and provincial. One user has only one record, it is not necessary to define or create a new user. You can show all the person accesses without adding a new user by showing their permissions (which are related to groups) in a modal window after authentication and by creating a link related to that permission you can let the use access such feature.

Comment: Thank you
I will implement the models and discuss with you again if there is a problem